# Proving $\sin P+\sin Q=2\sin\frac{P+Q}2\cos\frac{P-Q}2$ using the sin addition formula and double angle formula

Tags: trigonometry, proof-explanation

This question asks me to prove the validity of the trig identity by using the compound angle identities for $\sin(A+B)$ and $\sin(A-B)$

$$\sin P +\sin Q =2\sin\frac{P+Q}{2}\cos\frac{P-Q}{2}$$

I didn't get it at first so looked at the mark scheme and they set $$A+B=P$$ $$A-B=Q$$ and then got $$2\sin A\cos B=\sin(A+B)+\sin(A-B)$$ I get all the algebra, as in when they sub everything in to make it equal but I don't get why they suddenly got $A+B$ to equal $P$ and $Q$?

Also, if they got $\sin(A+B)+\sin(A-B)$ why would they not use the sin addition formula to actually prove it? How can they just say that $2\sin A\cos B=\sin(A+B)+\sin(A-B)$ and then sub $P$ and $Q$ back in to prove the question?

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

Comment: They did it because they could.  $A$ and $B$ don't have any significance on their own.  If you have *any* two numbers $x,y$ and can always find two other numbers where $x= A+B$ and $y= A-B$. (just let $A=\frac {x+y}2$ and $B=\frac {x-y}2$).  This can be a useful manipultion to make as expression appear simpler.

Comment: "How can they just say that 2sin(A)cos(B)=sin(A+B)+sin(A−B) "  I think they assume that written in that form it is self evident via the sin addition rules and that the reader would accept it (and if not, the reader would have no problem verifying for themselves that $\sin(A+B) + \sin(A-B) = \sin A\cos B + \cos A\sin B + \sin A\cos B - \cos A\sin B = 2\sin A\cos B$.)

Comment: This "trick" of replacing $X,Y$ with $A+B, A-B$ is quite useful and a standard trick in many areas.  For example to prove the AM. GM inequality that $\frac {a+b}2 \ge \sqrt{ab}$ (assuming $a,b\ge 0$) becomes easy if we replace $a$ with $M\pm N$ and $b$ with $M\mp N$ (assuming $N< M$... Note $M$ is simply the midpoint of $a,b$ and $N$ is just the distance of each from the midpoint).  Then we have $\frac {a+b}2=M$ and $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{(M-N)(M+N)}=\sqrt{M^2 - N^2} \le \sqrt {M^2} = M = \frac {a+b}2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They did it because they could.  $A$ and $B$ don't have any significance on their own.  If you have *any* two numbers $x,y$ and can always find two other numbers where $x= A+B$ and $y= A-B$. (just let $A=\frac {x+y}2$ and $B=\frac {x-y}2$).  This can be a useful manipultion to make as expression appear simpler.

But we could ignore it.

$P = \frac {P+Q}2 + \frac {P-Q}2$

And $Q = \frac {P+Q}2 -\frac {P-Q}2$.

So $\sin P = \sin (\frac {P+Q}2 + \frac {P-Q}2) = \sin \frac {P+Q}2\cos\frac {P-Q}2 + \cos \frac {P+Q}2\sin \frac {P-Q}2$.

(Interestingly that will true regardless of what $Q$ is.  We could take it as a trig identity that $\sin \theta = \sin (\frac {\theta+x}2 + \frac {\theta-x}2) = \sin \frac {\theta+x}2\cos\frac {\theta-x}2 + \cos \frac {\theta+x}2\sin \frac {\theta-x}2$ for all $x$.)

And $\sin Q =\sin (\frac {P+Q}2 - \frac {P-Q}2) = \sin \frac {P+Q}2\cos\frac {P-Q}2 - \cos \frac {P+Q}2\sin \frac {P-Q}2$

And so adding them up you get.... $2 \sin \frac {P+Q}2\cos \frac {P-Q}2$.

....

The people who wrote the proof simply thought it'd be easier to write and to follow if we replace $P$ with $A+B$ and $Q$ with $A-B$ (by letting $A:= \frac {P+Q}2$ and $B:=\frac {P-Q}2$) and prove  $\sin(A+B) - \sin(A-B) = 2\sin A\cos B$.

Was it easier to write and to follow?  Well, I'll let you be the jury on that.

=====

tl;dr

I think what the writer of the proof wanted to express but failed to make the point clear was this:

Prove $\sin P + \sin Q = 2\sin \frac {P+Q}2 \cos \sin \frac{P-Q}2$.

Proof:  Let's assign labels $A = \frac {P+Q}2$ and $B=\frac {P-Q}2$.  If we make this substitution we see that $A+B = \frac {P+Q}2 + \frac {P-Q}2 = \frac {2P}2 = P$ and that $A-B = \frac {P+Q}2 -\frac {P-Q}2 = \frac {2Q}2 = Q$.

Using this substitution our statement to prove becomes simply

$\sin(A+B) + \sin (A-B) = 2\sin A \cos B$.

ANd that follows immediately from the sine addition rule $\sin(A\pm B)=\sin A\cos B \pm \cos A\sin B$

(so $\sin(A+B) + \sin (A-B)= $
$(\sin A\cos B + \cos A\sin B) + (\sin A\cos B -\cos A\sin B) =$
$ 2\sin A\cos B$.)

....

Had the proof been written in that wording would it have been clearer?

Comment: Yeah it would've been much clearer I think the mark scheme I was looking at just simplified it down lots so I didn't understand where the different terms came from. Thanks so much for your reply, I understand now!

Answer (score 0):

The solutions of the linear system (in $A$ and $B$):
$\quad\begin{cases} A+B=P,\\A-B=Q, \end{cases}$

are precisely $\;A=\dfrac{P+Q}2,\enspace B=\dfrac{P-Q}2. $